# Access to container by his hostname from host-machine

Tags: docker, networking, containers, overlay

I have some docker containers which united single dockers overlay network.
Under this network every containers access by hostname (of container). But I cant access to container by hostname from host-mashine (my real host).

How I can get access to container by docker container hostname from my real machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by launching your own DNS resolver container.

```
docker run -d --name devdns -p 53:53/udp \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ruudud/devdns
```

Once you have run the DNS server. The server is mapped to your localhost. On linux you can edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add `nameserver 127.0.0.1` at the top. This change will be reverted after reboot.

Now if you launch a docker container

```
docker run -d --hostname tarunlalwani --name tlalwani ubuntu:16.04 sleep 2000
```

Now you can ping the container using either the container name or the hostname

```
$ ping tlalwani.dev
PING tlalwani.dev (172.17.0.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms

$ ping tarunlalwani.dev
PING tarunlalwani.dev (172.17.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
```

`dev` is the default domain name. You can change this using environment variables. For more details refer to https://github.com/ruudud/devdns

Comment: It is way! Can we use without domain name? Example: $ ping tlalwani

Comment: You can but you will have to build the image yourself and customize run.sh (https://github.com/ruudud/devdns/blob/master/run.sh)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `127.0.0.1 <hostname_inside_docker>` to your `hosts` file (on your local machine

Comment: It will be work if we use service with public port. But situation: have some containers with same ports and we should access to each container.