# resolve docker addresses from host

Tags: docker, dns

I am working on 2 different web projects who need to be able to communicate with each other. Both of these projects have their own dev environment made with docker-compose. To have them communicate with each other I have allready connected their docker networks, so they can reach each other.

To reach the sites from my dev machine I now expose port 80 of one docker container to my machine, and access the other one by its ip.

Is there a way to give both a .dev or similar address, and reach them localy using that address?

The docker-compose files are:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .docker/web
    volumes:
      - ./docroot:/var/www/html:z
    environment:
      - "XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.18.0.1"
    ports:
      -"80:80"
  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=notGettingIt
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=this_also_not
      - MYSQL_CIVI_DB=this_also_not
      - MYSQL_USER=this_also_not
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=this_also_not
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"



version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .docker/web
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html:z
    environment:
      - "XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.22.0.1"
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=chiro.dev
  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=notGettingIt
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=this_also_not
      - MYSQL_CIVI_DB=this_also_not
      - MYSQL_USER=this_also_not
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=this_also_not
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
```

Comment: as you are already matching the ports to localhost, you can access them with `localhost:PORT`

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250357/docker-compose-networking-hostname-not-resolving/46250906#46250906